# jQuery event.stopPropogation is causing page to change

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I can navigate to the page fine and all of the other AJAX jQuery stuff is working.

I have a `div` on the page in a collapseable set. In the header of each collapsible element I have a few `spans` which control the layout in the `div` header of each collapsible element.

So the PSEUDO layout looks like.

```
DIV -> Collapsible set
DIV -> Collapsible
   H4 -> Header info
       SPAN -> For a button to to the right of the header This span as an onclick in it with the following instructions:
        onclick=" //event.stopPropagation();
     window.ordselect = $(this).parents(\'.parentorder\'); 
     $(\'.choosebutton\').css(\'color\',\'black\');
      $(this).css(\'color\',\'red\');
      ">Choose</SPAN>';
```

I put in the `stopPropogation` so that when I click the `span` it doesn't open or close the surrounding `div`.

What I learned it does now is actually reset the page back to the original page of the application. If I remove the stopPropogation I get the desired result but it opens the collapsed `div`.

Here is the actual section of code. There are no other events attached to these items:

I think it has something to do with the A tag and that if I stop propogation that it is just considering it a link and therefore changing the page.

```
 <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true" data-content-theme="c" class="ui-collapsible-set ui-corner-all">

   <div id="ord1" class="parentorder ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-first-child" data-role="collapsible">

       <h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
       <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c" data-mini="true">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
               #:1<br>to: SYSCO by: Full Admina<br>@ 2013-11-22 00:00:00
    <span style="float:right;font-size:.7em;padding:3px" class="ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all">0</span>
    <span style="float: right; font-size: 0.7em; padding: 3px; color: red;" class=" choosebutton ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" onclick=" //event.stopPropagation();
     //window.ordselect = $(this).parents('.parentorder'); 
     $('.choosebutton').css('color','black');
      $(this).css('color','red');
      ">Choose</span>
      <span style="float:right;font-size:.7em;padding:3px" class="ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all">OPEN</span>
      <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span></span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus">&nbsp;</span></span></a></h4>
      <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-c" aria-hidden="false"><p id="orditems1" class="gradientbackground" style="font-size:.8em;border:1px solid green;padding:5px;margin:0px;color:white;text-align:center">ITEMS</p></div></div><div id="ord2" class="parentorder ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-last-child ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-role="collapsible"><h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-hover-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c" data-mini="true"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">#:2<br>to: SYSCO by: Full Admina<br>@ 2013-11-23 00:00:00<span style="float:right;font-size:.7em;padding:3px" class="ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all">0</span><span style="float: right; font-size: 0.7em; padding: 3px; color: black;" class=" choosebutton ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" onclick=" //event.stopPropagation();
     //window.ordselect = $(this).parents('.parentorder'); 
     $('.choosebutton').css('color','black');
      $(this).css('color','red');
      ">Choose</span>
      <span style="float:right;font-size:.7em;padding:3px" class="ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all">OPEN</span>
      <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
     </span>

    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-plus">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
```

ITEMS

Comment: can't use `stopPropagation` in `onclick` the way you are doing. Look at errors thrown in console. Suggest you use jQuery only and remove all inline `onclick`.

Comment: got it working by adding these at the end of the onclick block. yes agreed I should bind some handlers as well.

Comment: spoke to soon..moving everything to an bind...